# Xfce4 on WSL with VcXsrv doesn't update properly

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xfce4, vcxsrv

I got Xfce4 installed on WSL. It's working except for the part where the graphics doesn't update properly:

[image]

I have to keep moving things around to trigger an update. Is there any way to fix that?

PS: It updates fine when I'm not running VcXsrc in "one window" mode.

Windows 10, WSL Bash xforwarded to VcXsrv

Comment: Is it showing full ram usage in Windows?

Comment: Biswa No it isn't.

Comment: Did you try with only [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)?

Comment: I have tried both Xming (public domain version) and VcXsrv. They both behave the same.